# Limitar caracteres em div e exibir pontos apenas se necessário?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho o seguinte:

```
$("h2").text(function(index, currentText) {
 return currentText.substr(0, 100) + '...';
});
```

Ele limita o texto da tag h2 em 100 caracteres e exibi os três pontos no final, no entanto os pontos são exibidos mesmo que os caracteres não cheguem em 100, de maneira que não faz sentido ter os pontos se o título já esta completo. Como posso fazer pra exibir os pontos apenas se o h2 ultrapassar o limite?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Como posso fazer pra exibir os pontos apenas se o h2 for ultrapassar o limite?

Basta adicionar a condição de só executar o código se a string for maior que 100 caracteres, concorda?

```
$("h2").text(function(index, currentText) {
    if(currentText.length > 100)
        return currentText.substr(0, 100) + '...';

    return currentText;
});
```

Acredito que isso responde a pergunta, não sei qual a finalidade do seu código, mas talvez o que você realmente precise seja utilizar [ellipsis](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp).